# Conditional Formatting with multiple text values

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns. I want to change the color of column B based on selected text in column A. 
for example:-
If I select a specific text in column A that is "ABC" or "CBD" or "EFG".

value in column B should not be less than 0, if the value is less than 0 than format the cell with color red and if it more than 0 than color it with green.

I have been trying it with conditional format, but eventually its not working it out.

Comment: Conditional formatting does not work on selection, but on the value that is stored in a cell. Do you really mean "select" or are you struggling to find a suitable word? Do you maybe mean "entered into a cell"??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.  First you say you want to change the color of 'Column B' based on the text value, then you say you want to change the color based on whether the number is greater than or less than 0 but you didn't say what column these numbers were in.

I made a sample that will change the color of 'Column B' to either red or green based on the value of that number.  But if you want to change the color of a cell based on the text value then you will have to create a rule for each of the text values you are dealing with then assign it to whatever cells you wish to affect.

[image]

If you could clarify the question for us a little, we could probably help you out with a more accurate solution.

Comment: I`m sorry for the confusion.
I`ll clarify it.
Column A has text some text containing text1 and text2, but the value in column B should not be less than 0,
if the value is less than 0, it should highlighted as RED else Green.
I understand that my question contains multiple conditions, but If i can get a a VB code for the above parameters it will be a great Help.